# App crashes or freezes when parsing Realm models

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I have this Realm model definition:

```
class PSTChatThread: RLMObject {
    dynamic var channelName = ""
    dynamic var environment = RLMObject(object: PSTChannelEnv.className())
    dynamic var chatMessages = RLMArray(objectClassName: PSTMessage.className())
}

class PSTChannelEnv: RLMObject {
    dynamic var associatedPlaceId = 0
    dynamic var chattingWithUuid = ""
    dynamic var chattingWithUsername = ""
    dynamic var hasSessionEnded = false
    dynamic var unreadMessages = 0
}

class PSTMessage: RLMObject {

    // type
    dynamic var typeRaw = ""
    var type: PSTProtocolMsgTypes {
        get {
            if let a = PSTProtocolMsgTypes(rawValue: typeRaw) {
               return a
           }
           return .ChatMsg
        }
     }

    // envelope
    dynamic var channel = ""
    dynamic var timeoken = 0

 }

class ChatMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var msgId = ""
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var username = ""
    dynamic var uuid = ""
    dynamic var associatedPlaceId = -1
 }

 class ACKMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var forId = ""
    dynamic var uuid = ""
 }

 class UserTypingMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var uuid = ""
 }

 class UserStoppedTypingMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var uuid = ""
 }

 class SessionUpdateMsg: PSTMessage {
     dynamic var hasSessionEnded = false
     dynamic var uuid = ""
 }

 class ContactDetailsMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var accessLevel = -1
    dynamic var uuid = ""
 } 

 class ReadReceiptMsg: PSTMessage {
    dynamic var uuid = ""
 }
```

- When I run the app, it crashes in: `prop.column = table.add_column_link(tightdb::DataType(prop.type), prop.name.UTF8String, *linkTable);` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
- Under the assumption that models are parses top-to-bottom, if I move `PSTChatThread` to the bottom, the app just freezes. No crash or anything, just becomes unresponsive.

It appears there's some problem with `PSTChatThread` definition. If this gets commented out, everything appears to work fine.

This happens whenever I make a `RMRealm` call or any other query call to the models.

In case my subclassing logic, I'd like to ask one more thing. Is there any way that `PSTMessage` does not get persisted to the schema but only it's subclasses do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line

```
dynamic var environment = RLMObject(object: PSTChannelEnv.className())
```

It just needs to be

```
dynamic var environment: PSTChannelEnv
```

The reason we have objectClassName... is because you are creating an array with type objectClassName. When doing a to-one relationship, you already know the object class, so you can set the type directly.

Here are more docs on the [setting up your models in Realm](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.5/#models)

We should throw an error though when you try to do something like this. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks buddy, that is very helpful. Do you have an answer for my subquestion? Namely if I can avoid having the superclass `PSTMessage` inserted as a table in the schema.

Comment: Not at the moment, empty tables don't have any performance impacts though. Could you explain a bit more why you want to avoid having it in the schema?

Comment: There's no rationale actually. Just doesnt feel right to have a table that won't get any values during its lifetime. Thanks again.

Comment: Yea I know what you mean, that's usually what people say when they look at their .realm file. I've filed an issue https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1466

Comment: Do you have any idea why `channelEnv.chatMessages.addObject(message)` produces a crash with this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type does not match RLMArray'`? Message is of type `PSTMessage` and channelEnv is `PSTChatThread` as these are declared in the question, but corrected to reflect your suggestion in your answer.